# Running App Dot Indicator Showing on Wrong Workspace

Tags: gnome, 22.04, workspaces, wayland, dock

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with Wayland.

The issue is that if I use "activities view" or "show applications" to move an app to another workspace, then click back to the workspace I was using, the running app dot indicator is still present for favorite apps. This is not an issue for apps that are not in the favorite category.

I have selected to isolate running apps to each workspace, so my dock only shows apps that are running on that workspace. When I toggle back and forth between relevant workspaces the bug sorts itself out (meaning dot goes away on primary workspace). It's just immediately after sending the app to another workspace that the problem presents itself.

Comment: Are you using any Gnome extensions? There's a somewhat recent bug that might be what you're seeing. Please check here to review: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock/+bug/2004554.

Comment: Does the Ubuntu 22.04 dock itself qualify as a gnome extension? I do have gnome tweaks installed, but I don't think I have any actual extensions. How can I check and be sure?

Comment: To show enabled Gnome extensions, you can run this command: `gnome-extensions list --enabled.` If you're running just the Ubuntu dock, you should see `ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com.` If this is the case, review the bug report, as it sounds very much like the issue that you're running into.

Comment: Thank you I have commented there now, although reading the comments there could be two separate bugs as there are two different failure modes mentioned. My command result is this:
ding@rastersoft.com
ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com

Comment: I don't think those active extensions would cause the problem that you're seeing. However, you could always install the Gnome extensions manager (`sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager `) and manage your extensions from there. If it were me, I'd disable all but the Ubuntu Dock extension and confirm your issue (limits possible contributing variables).